# How to differentiate between uses of the AS keyword when parsing a query

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing, antlr4

When parsing a query and I land on the keyword "AS" , how do I determine if it's an alias for a table or an alias for a column?

```
    @Override public void visitTerminal(TerminalNode node) {
        switch (node.getText().toUpperCase()) {
        case "AS":
            processTerminalNodeAs(node);
            break;
        }
   }
```

For example:

```
SELECT LoyaltyNumber AS LN FROM Transaction AS T;
```

The parser will find the keyword AS twice. The first occurrence is an alias for a column, the second occurrence is an alias for a table.

Comment: Also `CAST(expr AS type)`

Comment: @JoeStefanelli please clarify what you mean.

Comment: The parser also needs to recognize the context of an alias (correlation name) when the optional `AS` keyword is not present. Consider e.g. `SELECT LoyaltyNumber LN FROM Transaction T`

Comment: @nicomp The CAST function is another place where the AS keyword occurs. I assume your parser would also have to recognize it there as well.

Comment: That's easy.  I never use `as` for table aliases; only for column aliases.

Comment: I have to parse any syntactically correct query. I can't impose style rules on the SQL.

Comment: You need to show more of your parser structure to answer that question, but most of the SQL parsers I've seen use an LALR(1) parser generator, which has no trouble since the syntactic states are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `visitTerminal` visitor method for tokens you require context for. Instead use the methods for visiting the containing rules. This depends on your grammar (which you haven't referenced here), so I can only guess. But you likely have something like: `SELECT selectItem* fromClause whereClause? ...`. The `selectItem` rule may contain something like:

```
selectItem: expr alias?;
```

with

```
alias: AS_SYMBOL? identifier;
```

Now you can use the `visitSelectItem` visitor method to determine if there's a column/subquery alias, by examining the passed in context (roughly: `context.alias().AS_SYMBOL`).

This is just one example of where the AS keyword can be used, but the principle is the same for all other ocurrences. Visit the containing rule (might not be the directly containing rule (here e.g. `alias`), but a higher one, which gives you enough context to determine which AS you are looking at.